# How to get c source dir not cmake compile dir

Tags: c, cmake, libxml2

I have article.html in src for test libxml, I hope read it with relative path '.article', but in clion, cmake change current dir to "/home/roroco/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/c9a7a4c5/c9a7a4c5/Debug0", My question is: is there `get_current_source_dir()`?

**update** here is my ex.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    puts(get_current_dir_name());
//    /home/roroco/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/b321980/b321980/Debug
    FILE *f = fopen('article.html', "r");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
//    Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
    return (0);
};
```

here is my files tree

```
- ex.c
- CMakeLists.txt
- article.html
```

here is my [CMakeLists.txt](https://gist.github.com/roroco/c3c1f14cba96e3b4ead5)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a C language question, you'll get better responses if you remove the C tag. Please provide some examples of solutions you tried to implement.

Comment: @Erik, it's about c, and i update my code

Comment: Very good. The SIGSEGV occurred because you didn't check the return value of ```fopen``` for NULL.  You'll have more success if you used an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Comment: Are you asking that 'article.html' should be appended with get_current_dir_name like "/home/roroco/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/b321980/b321980/Debug/article.html" when fopen try to open that?

Comment: @Erik, If I use this code in other pc, I need to change absolute path in at least once, is there more confident way?

Comment: @Viswesn I use cmake, how to automatically "appended" file?

Comment: Well perhaps if cmake copied the target file 'article.html' to the compilation directory that would solve your conundrum.  Otherwise you might investigate passing the path to the file into your program via the the command line, specifically in ```argv```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the proper way to solve this is to put `article.html` into `/home/roroco/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/b321980/b321980/Debug`, here is what you can do:

In CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_definitions("-DSOURCE_PATH=\"${CMAKE_SOURCE_PATH}\"")
```

And in ex.c:

```
fopen(SOURCE_PATH "article.html", "r");
```